# Semi-infinite Wave Equation with piewise initial conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

We have the following for a semi-infinite interval
$$ u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx} = 0 \quad \quad 0 < c < \infty $$
Initial conditions are piecewise defined.
$$ u(x,0) = \begin{cases} 0, & 0<x<2  \\ 1, & 2<x<3 \\ 0,&  x>3
 \end{cases} $$
$$ u_t(x,0) = 0 $$
We have boundary conditions:
$$ u_x(0,t) = 0 $$
$\textbf{My attempt}$ at this is as follows:
We use D'Alembert solution:
$$u(x,t) = F(x-ct) + G(x+ct) $$
We note that we have a problem with zero initial velocity. This means that if $u(x,0) = f(x)$ then we have that:
$$ u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}f(x-ct) + \frac{1}{2} f(x+ct)$$
We note $f(x)$ is given piecewise but it only takes on positive arguments. $f(x-ct)$ has negative arguments though. We summarize this as follows

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{Interval} & F(x) = \frac{1}{2}f(x-ct) & G(x) = \frac{1}{2}f(x+ct)&u(x,t)\\
\hline
0<x<ct & ? & 0 & ? + 0 \\
\hline
ct<x < 2-ct & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
2-ct<x<2+ct & 0 & \frac{1}{2}(1)&\frac{1}{2}\\
\hline
2+ct <x<3-ct & \frac{1}{2}(1) & \frac{1}{2}(1)&1\\
\hline
3-ct < x< 3+ct & \frac{1}{2}(1) & 0&\frac{1}{2} \\
\hline x > 3+ct & 0 & 0&0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
So solving for $x \in (ct, \infty)$ is not a problem. One will simply ass up the row to get $u(x,t)$.\
$\textbf{The Problem}$ arises there where the $?$ has been placed as $f(x)$ takes a negative argument. We try and solve for it using our boundary conditions.
$$ u(x,t)_x = \frac{dF(x-ct)}{d(x-ct)} + \frac{G(x+ct)}{d(x+ct)} $$
$$ \therefore u(0,t)_x = \frac{dF(ct)}{d(ct)} + \frac{G(ct)}{d(ct)} = 0  $$
$$ -\frac{1}{c}\frac{dF(-ct)}{d(t)} + \frac{1}{c}\frac{G(ct)}{d(t)} = 0  $$
$$\therefore \frac{dF(-ct)}{d(t)} = \frac{G(ct)}{d(t)} $$
$$ \therefore F(-ct) = G(ct) + k$$
Let $z$ denote a negative argument. Then we have
$$ F(z) = G(-z) + k $$
$$\therefore F(x-ct) = G(ct-x) + k$$
Now from the table, we have that $G(ct-x) = 0, \quad 0<x<ct$. So should we assume $F(x-ct) = k$ for this interval. There is no way of determining $k$ right? I think so. Thus the first interval has solution $u(x,t) = k$ where $k$ is an undetermined constant.

$\textbf{Question:}$ please help me undertand whether what I have done is indeed correct. If it is wrong, please help me to correct it. If it is correct and you feel I should be using a better method, please help me understand that method please. Thank you very much for your time.

P.S. this question is from [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/consider-wave-equation-semi-infinite-interval-free-boundary-chapter-12.4-problem-3e-solution-9780321797063-exc)